# Extend the ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe, instantiation.active_record hook

Tags: ruby, activerecord, notifications, instantiation, activesupport

I am exploring `ActiveSupport::Notifications`, and would like more information about `'instantiation.active_record'`, than just the `:record_count` and `:class_name` [[1]](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#instantiation-active-record). For example,

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe /instantiation.active_record/ do |*args|

  args.status #Database or ActiveRecord return status
  args.result #The actual result set returned
  args.etc .. #Any other info I can collect on the event

  # Additional code ...
end
```

Can this be done, and if so, how?

Update:
Thanks to Tom and Pavel below. Part of the challenge, is that I am building a 3rd party gem, that will analyze all SQL returns of the host app, without requiring the modification of their code. Basically, plug it into the Gemfile, do a bundle, and away you go.

I am considering [extending ActiveRecord::Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase), and [using the method append_info_to_payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633361/how-to-add-attribute-to-existing-notifications-payload/14374349#14374349), but thus far have neither working in a gem.

As an example, I would like to overwrite the ActiveRecord::Querying find_by_sql() method's payload, to look like this:

```
payload = {
  record_count: result_set.length,
  class_name: name,
  result_set: result_set
}
```

In testing, and manually editing my local ActiveRecord gem, this delivers the complete result_set via ActiveSupport::Notifications pub/sub.

Answer: So, the answer is to use the `class_eval` method, and overwrite the find_by_sql method in ActiveRecord::Querying:

```
ActiveRecord::Querying.class_eval do
  def find_by_sql(sql, binds = [], preparable: nil, &block)
    result_set = connection.select_all(sanitize_sql(sql), "#{name} Load", binds, preparable: preparable)
    column_types = result_set.column_types.dup
    columns_hash.each_key { |k| column_types.delete k }
    message_bus = ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrumenter

    payload = {
        record_count: result_set.length,
        class_name: name,
        result_set: result_set
    }

    message_bus.instrument("instantiation.active_record", payload) do
      result_set.map { |record| instantiate(record, column_types, &block) }
    end
  end
end
```

I added this to my gem's `initializer.rb` file.

Final: I created two pull requests on ActiveRecord, to have the result_set pass forward in the payload for use in ActiveSupport::Notifications: [querying.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34712) and [join_dependency.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34713).

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be done, and if so, how?

I don't think so.

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d41ec8180d3df391e5fc0189f499d8689ca27e03/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb#L105-L112) and [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/89595aff8ee6d7dd05f84570a84aa9b4232a5207/activerecord/lib/active_record/querying.rb#L45-L52) - in both cases `payload` is a Hash with only `record_count` and `class_name` options. No extra options than described in the guide.

Comment: Pavel, even though you said it could not be done, your two links headed me in the right direction. I am giving you the bounty ... Thanks!  ...  Oh, never say can't. :)

Comment: Thank you! Monkeypatching can do everything in Ruby :) I believe, `ActiveSupport::Notifications` was initially designed for simple logging and watching.

Comment: Yeah, I am not crazy about the term "Monkeypatching", but I could not find a better way to change behavior of the ActiveRecord gem "from my gem", and without adding code to the host app. If someone can demonstrate, I am more than happy to listen.

Comment: I don't think that there is another way. Yep, we have to patch framework when it has no needed API from scratch.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I created two pull requests on ActiveRecord. See above.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [custom hook](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#creating-custom-events) with `::instrument`. You can then define a payload that has `status`, `result_set`, etc, and define their behavior in the block.

You can find more robust documentation on `::instrument` and `::subscribe` [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html).

EDIT: I was looking into this more and came across [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14374349/5399937).  It looks like the method `append_info_to_payload` is what you are looking for. It has been moved to a [private method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Instrumentation.html#method-i-append_info_to_payload) is Rails 5.

One last edit: If you are feeling brave the notification is used [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d41ec8180d3df391e5fc0189f499d8689ca27e03/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb#L112) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/querying.rb#L52) if you want to insert your extra payload directly .